# How can I get all the objects in a Django model that have a specific value for a ForeignKey field?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a Model with a Foreign Key of "Parent"

```
class Item(models.Model):
parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

This is the FK model

```
class Parent(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

I am trying to run a query that gets all Items with a parent of "xyz" I get nothing

```
Item.objects.filter(parent="xyz")
```

When I try:

```
Item.objects.filter(parent.name="xyz")
```

Or:

```
Item.objects.filter(str(parent)="xyz")
```

I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a double underscore in the keyword passed to `filter()` to access fields in a foreign key relationship. Like this:

```
Item.objects.filter(parent__name="xyz")
```

[Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference for Googlers, with recent versions of Django you have to use an additional method in the keyword.  For example, instead of `parent__name` you have to do `parent__name__exact`.  Cato's link contains other examples.